# aws test-invoke-authorizer: 'token' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 1024

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm getting an error when trying to invoke my custom authorizer. I'm calling it like this:

```
aws --region eu-central-1 iot test-invoke-authorizer --authorizer-name go-dev-iot-authorizer --token "$TOKEN" --token-signature "$SIGNATURE"
```

(where `$TOKEN` and `$SIGNATURE` are bash variables containing the JWT token and its AWS signature)

And this is the response I'm getting:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the TestInvokeAuthorizer operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '[MY TOKEN IS PRINTED HERE]' at 'token' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 1024
```

I can see that there is indeed a 1024 character limit on the token field here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/api-com.amazonaws.iot.identity.TestInvokeAuthorizer.html

My access token is 1418 chars, so it's clear that it's surpasses this limit. My question is, is this only a restriction for the test-invoke-authorizer command or does this limit also apply for the real thing? I'm  using a normal JWT token from a standard identity provider (Keycloak), so there's not really much I can do to shorten it. Am I somehow using this wrong or is there really a 1024 character limit for JWT tokens in AWS authorizers?

Answer (score 0):

aws iot test-invoke-authorizer exercise same constraints to help debug actual custom authorization calls.

Unfortunately AWS Iot DeviceGateway has header size limitation which restricts Custom Auth token length to 1024 chars currently.

If your JWT token contains any authorization info then I would suggest to strip that off to keep it limited to authentication only as authorization is meant to be done by the iot policy documents returned by your authorizer.

---

**Update**: AWS Iot DeviceGateway now supports greater than 1024 chars custom auth token.